# The hight: 100% is not applied and the website shrank. How can I set it to Height: 100% using React + MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

[image]

As you can see that the App bar shrank the webpage side. The Root component is still full 100% and height. The App Bar component is 'App Bar with a primary search field' from https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/

My code is here.

```
     <MainWrapper className='App'>

        <div style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}>
        <Visible when={isLogged}>
          <Navbar />
        </Visible>
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/map'
            component={MapPage}
            isLogged={isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/login'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/profile'
            component={UserProfile}
            isLogged={isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/login'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/login'
            component={Login}
            isLogged={!isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/map'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/registration'
            component={Registration}
            isLogged={!isLogged}
            redirectTo={'/map'}
          />
          <PrivateRouter
            path='/'
            component={{}}
            isLogged={false}
            redirectTo={'/login'}
          />
        </Switch>
        </div>
      </MainWrapper>
    );
  }
}

const MainWrapper = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
`;
```

This is Visible Component

```
export default ({ when, element = null, children }) => when ? children : element;
```

I've been switching around the page to make it full height. If I get rid of App Bar, then it comes normal. Still could not figure it out :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by removig  `<MainWrapper className='App'>` like  `<MainWrapper>` . Because **className='App'** use react default styles.